# Centering polygon on specific coordinates using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, centroids

I need to place a set of polygons onto a set of points, so that each polygon is centered on its corresponding point.

How do I do that?

In MapInfo I can just manually edit the coordinates of the center, but there does not seem to be an equivalent in QGIS.

Answer (score 7):

**This answer is for QGIS 3.4.**

*See this answer for earlier versions: [Moving vectors to specified coordinates in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13433/moving-vectors-to-specified-coordinates-in-qgis)*

I was able to do this by creating a centroid for a polygon:
[image]

Then moving the polygon feature with the move tool--you can snap to centroid that you just added:
[image]

Then move to the target point, again snapping (this answer describes how to configure snapping in QGIS 3: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278376/31 .

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jay! Had to upgrade to 3.4 (snapping to the centroid didn't work in 2.18), but this solves my problem perfectly.

Comment: Is there any way to do this (moving a polygon from its centroid location to a new location - hopefully lat and long) programmatically or via a data table?

Comment: @Herb - I think you should click the green checkmark next to it to accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use QGIS expressions with Geometry generator or Geometry by expression (see here for [details on these two options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) to automatically shift your polygons.

Let's assume you have several polygons that should be shifted the a set of points. You need to have a common attribute to associate a point to each polygon - in my case it's the field id, which contain a common, unique value on both layers.

Use the following expression - it shifts (`translate`) each polygon (`$geometry`) in a certain distance in x and y direction. The value for the shift in x/y direction is calclulated as follows: get the `x`/`y` value of each point (the geometry of the layer named `points`: `geometry (get_feature_by_id ('points', [n]))`) with the same id as the current polygon (thus repleace `[n]` from before with `$id`). From this `x`/`y` value subtract the `x`/`y` value of the current polygon's centroid (`centroid ($geometry)`) - all together:

```
translate( 
    $geometry, 
    x(
        geometry (
            get_feature_by_id (
                'points',
                $id
            )
        )
    )-
    x (centroid ($geometry)),
    y(
        geometry (
            get_feature_by_id (
                'points',
                $id
            )
        )
    )-
    y (centroid ($geometry))
)
```

*Screenshot: orange=original polygons, white dots= points where the shifted polygons should be centered; blue=polygons shifted with the expression from above (using geometry generator):*

[image]